# How to improve OpenGL texture render performance

Tags: opengl, textures

I am using OpenGL to render text in my app, in my implementation, a glyph is a small texture, the render works correct, but the performance is too low. The following is my code fragment, when layout contains 8000 glyphs, it took about 200 ms to finish rendering (the render function), I think the "for loop" is the key to slow down the render process, perhaps render every single glyph as a texture is a “fool way” :(, Is there a way to improve the text render performance?

```
#define FONT_BITMAP_WIDTH 128
#define FONT_BITMAP_HEIGHT 128

void setupOpenGL() {
    ...
    ...
    // create pixel buffer object to render texture
    glGenBuffers(1, &_pixelBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, _pixelBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 
                 FONT_BITMAP_WIDTH * FONT_BITMAP_HEIGHT, 
                 NULL, 
                 GL_STREAM_DRAW);
    ...
    ...
    // create texture
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                 0,
                 GL_RED,
                 FONT_BITMAP_WIDTH,
                 FONT_BITMAP_HEIGHT,
                 0,
                 GL_RED,
                 GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                 NULL);
    ...
    ...
}

void render(Glyph** glyphs, int count) {

    // render every single glyph
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i ++) {
            // caculate glyph vertex position
            float x0 = glyphs[i]->rect.origin.x;
            float y0 = glyphs[i]->rect.origin.y;
            float x1 = x0 + FONT_BITMAP_WIDTH;
            float y1 = y0 + FONT_BITMAP_HEIGHT;

            float positions[] = {
                x0, y1, 0.0, 1.0,
                x1, y1, 0.0, 1.0,
                x0, y0, 0.0, 1.0,
                x1, y0, 0.0, 1.0,
            };

            float textureCoords[] = {
                0.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 1.0f,
                0.0f, 0.0f,
                1.0f, 0.0f,
            };

            // submit vertex and texture coordinate data
            glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 
                            0, 
                            sizeof(positions), 
                            positions);
            glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 
                            sizeof(positions), 
                            sizeof(textureCoords), 
                            textureCoords);

            // submit texture image data
            glBufferSubData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 
                            0, 
                            FONT_BITMAP_WIDTH * FONT_BITMAP_HEIGHT, 
                            glyphs[i]->bitmap_ref);
            glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                            0,
                            0,
                            0,
                            FONT_BITMAP_WIDTH,
                            FONT_BITMAP_HEIGHT,
                            GL_RED,
                            GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                            0);

            // render glyph
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    }

    // present render result
    openglFlushBuffer();
}
```

Comment: What do you intend to do by `glTexSubImage2D`? I recommend to load the texture with all the glyphs to the GPU. "choose" the proper rectangular section from the texture by the texture coordinates for each glyph.

Comment: Yes, I make the glyphs to be a texture atlas, choose a glyph(which to be drawn) by texture coordinates, now the performance is improved.